# Does the subtree under x being splayed become necessarily balanced after the splay operation?

Tags: algorithm, splay-tree

Here is the problem:

Let T be a splay tree on n nodes, and let x be a node of T. Consider a splay operation at x. Does the subtree under x become necessarily balanced (i.e., the height of the subtree rooted at x in the splay tree becomes O(logn) after the splay operation?

I spent lots of time on it, but still frustrated....I appreciate your answer.

Comment: If you have another question, that you can't figure out on your own editing someone's answer isn't the right thing to do. You can always ask another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider the absolute worst-case where T looks something like this:

```
y
 \
  y
   \
   ...
     \
      x
```

where the `y`s are arbitrary nodes. Once you splay `x`, the tree will look something like this:

```
  x
 /
y
 \
  y
 / \
y   y
   / \
  y   y
     / \
    y  ...
         \
          y
```

(again, with `y`s as arbitrary nodes). The depth then, is still `O(n)` in this case.

**EDIT:** Realized I messed up the "after" tree, so updating my answer with a more correct example.

Comment: Thank you. Dennis. It's helpful. So, after the splay operation, T should be like this:      
        x
       /
      y
       \
        y
       / \
      y   y
         /
        y...
which is not balanced, right?

Comment: A comment isn't the best place to try to draw a tree. I added the "before" and "after" in my answer so that it would be visible for both of us.

Comment: @BiWu With regards to that example you tried to give in that rejected edit; try again with a longer tree; you'll see the pattern.

Comment: Thanks~ I'll make a try. Just takes some time :)

Answer (score 0):

No.  See [these notes](https://www.cs.umd.edu/users/meesh/420/Notes/MountNotes/lecture10-splay.pdf).  The average depth of traversed nodes is cut in half, but that doesn't guarantee that a balanced tree results.